# action without button on swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, action, data-manipulation

I’m new at this and I’m wondering if it’s possible in swift or objective-C to make an action without the interaction of a button or any type of user interaction? So far i can send an array to a second ViewController but I need to process the data and show it in a UIPickerview and I don’t know how...

i pass the data with this:

```
func pepareSegueWithIdentifier(segue:UIStoryboardSeque, senderAnyObject?){
    var detailVC = segue.destinationViewController as ViewNotLogged;
    detailVC.pickerData1 = pickerData
  }
```

i creater the var in the second viewcontroller

```
    class ViewNotLogged: UIViewcontroller, UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerDataDelegate{
var pickerData1=[String]()
}
```

but after this i dont nowaht to do to modify the data or even check it with println()

Comment: If your second view controller shows? You could override viewDidLoad() method there and check there.

Comment: Thank you Alex, now i can at least see what i send and yes i use performSegueWithIdentifier to show the second view controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For my comment above - you could do something like this:

```
class ViewNotLogged: UIViewController {
    var pickerData1 = [String]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        println("My data \(pickerData1)")
    }
}
```

And try not to implements `UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate` before VC don't ready

---

UPD:

Emulate with my data and it works.
Here my code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var pickerData = ["Sw", "Sw"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        var detailVC = segue.destinationViewController as ViewNotLogged;
        detailVC.pickerData1 = pickerData
    }
}

class ViewNotLogged: UIViewController {
    var pickerData1 = [String]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        println("My data \(pickerData1)")
    }
}
```

In IB I just have two VC first is `ViewController` and second is `ViewNotLogged`. Also I have button at first, that make modal storyboard segue.

Comment: when i should use it? should i override the class after i get all the data?

Comment: No, I mean you should override viewDidLoad() method of your presenting VC and you could print pickerData1 array content in this method.

Comment: i did but  var is empty.... i check the original pickerData before change the VC and have all the data

Comment: And it's called this line of code? println("My data \(pickerData1)"), so you have log that looks like something like this "My data []"?

Comment: ye, the original (pickerData) is [data1, data2] but the pickerData1 is []

Comment: I really don’t know, i have 0 errors and the project do the simulation smoothly but the data still [], is there another way to send the data? or another place to initialize the variable?

Comment: There are thousands of ways to do this, but it's better for you to understand this one first. if code is similar to my, but it dons't logging, then error could be in interface (storyboard)

Comment: i have no error in the loggin process but what i cant understand is why if i check the first variable just before move from the VC and  in the peparation  asing the first to the second like i show it before i get a blank. im gonna try your literal code

Comment: it work fine, but still hace to figure it out what is wrong with my original code, thanks for all the  help

Comment: after check you code i see a little difference  i was using a func pepareSegueWithIdentifier and your was  func prepareForSegue and because reasons  mine don’t send the data